# How to serve static files (like images) in a combined django-react application

Tags: python, reactjs, django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

**This is the first web application I'm developing by combining django and reactjs, in fact react is new to me.
Please if my approach is wrong I'm open for correction**.
When developing with purely django, I find no difficulty with static and media files.
It is clear that the elements involved are the media root and static root,
respectively. In that case, all I need to do is to specify the static/media root in the
settings.py in the django app as shown below:

```
settings.py

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')  
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL =  '/media/images/'

urls.py

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
        + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

However, when I combine django and react the configuration changes since django is configured
to look at `index.html` file in react, in which case an additional element called `STATICFILES DIRS`
is added to the seetings.py file to specify the path to  react `index.html`. In fact, my django app
configuration looks like this when I combine django and react:

```
settings.py

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL =  '/media/images/'

urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
        + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
    ...
]
```

Everything works well as when I'm developing purely with django except that when I combine django and react in development **the images I upload refuse to displayed
on the browser since any path that does not match with the specified paths in `urlpattern` are redirected
to react.**  `re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))` So the image path is being redirected. When I click the image link in the admin file, instead of
the image to get displayed, I'm redirected to react also. I have made research online but I can't find any resources
that explained properly how to configure the django static root and media root to be able to serve files (
like images uploaded to the database) content.
**Please, do I display images and media on the browser?** In production, I would like to serve static files of the
django-react app with aws s3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have added the build folder to installed apps

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ build, ]`

If DEBUG use STATICFILES_DIRS else use STATIC_ROOT. Add this code in the settings.py file.

`if DEBUG: STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] else: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

In the urls.py file

`urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]`

Then run `python manage.py collectstatic`

You should also install whitenoise `pip install whitenoise`